# Separate heatmap ranges for each row in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap

I'm trying to build a timeseries heatmap along a 24-hour day on each day of the week, and I want to have each day be subject within its own values only. Here's what I've done in Plotly so far.
[image]

The problem is the "highest" color only goes to the one on the 2nd row. My desired output, made in Excel, is this one:

[image]

Each row clearly shows its own green color since they each of them have separate conditional formatting.

My code:

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test0.csv', header=None)
fig = px.imshow(df, color_continuous_scale=['red', 'green'])
fig.update_coloraxes(showscale=False)
fig.show()
```

The csv file:

```
0,0,1,2,0,5,2,3,3,5,8,4,7,9,9,0,4,5,2,0,7,6,5,7
1,3,4,9,4,3,3,2,12,15,6,9,1,4,3,1,1,2,5,3,4,2,5,8
9,6,7,1,3,4,5,6,9,8,7,8,6,6,5,4,5,3,3,6,4,8,9,10
8,7,8,6,7,5,4,6,6,7,8,5,5,6,5,7,5,6,7,5,8,6,4,4
3,4,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,3,4,4,2,2,1,1,1,2,4,3
3,5,4,4,4,6,5,5,5,4,3,7,7,8,7,6,7,6,6,3,4,3,3,3
5,4,4,5,4,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,2,1,1,4,3,4,5,4,4,3,4
```

Comment: this is an interesting problem, and I will circle back when I have a little time, but I think you would most likely want to use `go.Heatmap` and add each row as a separate trace – however this would also require you to determine the colors for each row too.

Comment: What is missing in the graph you are currently creating? Is it the annotation of the figures? I feel I am missing an understanding of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it! I had to make the heatmaps by row and combine them.

```py
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import calendar

df = pd.read_csv('test0.csv', header=None)
# initialize subplots with vertical_spacing as 0 so the rows are right next to each other
fig = make_subplots(rows=7, cols=1, vertical_spacing=0)
# shift sunday to first position
days = list(calendar.day_name)
days = days[-1:] + days[:-1]

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row_list = row.tolist()
    sub_fig = go.Heatmap(
        x=list(range(0, 24)), # hours
        y=[days[index]], # days of the week
        z=[row_list], # data
        colorscale=[
            [0, '#FF0000'],
            [1, '#00FF00']
        ],
        showscale=False
    )
    # insert heatmap to subplot
    fig.append_trace(sub_fig, index + 1, 1)

fig.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please add some description explaining what is does and how it solves the problem or add comments in the source code at appropriate places.